# control identifier is not identifying child window for save menu options

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pywinauto

I want to automate Wireshark for certain tests. I am using pywinauto module over python , but stuck while getting the child window for options under save menu. I tried app.WiresharkRTPStreamAnalysisrtpcap.Save.ForwardStreamCSV.print_control_identifiers(), but it states ElementNotFoundError. Also tried app.WiresharkRTPStreamAnalysisrtpcap.print_control_identifiers(), but it only shows the control identifier upto save options, but not the options under save button. The attached image are the options under 'save' and I want the control identifiers of all those options under save button. Please help.[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL4kc.png)